# Find the value of- $\lim_{x \rightarrow -\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{1000} \frac{x^k}{k!}$

Tags: limits, summation, solution-verification

> **QUESTION:** Find the value of-  $$\lim_{x \rightarrow -\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{1000} \frac{x^k}{k!}$$

---

**MY ANSWER:** Since $x→-\infty$ therefore the summation will look like-
$$ \frac{-\infty^1}{1!}+ \frac{-\infty^2}{2!} + \frac{-\infty^3}{3!} + \frac{-\infty^4}{4!}$$

Now, we know that $${-\infty^{even}}=\infty$$

And $1000$ can be broken down into 500 *pairs*. And since $k$ is finite the terms will look like $$ -\infty + \infty -\infty +\infty-.....$$

Hence, we can conclude that the overall limit of the summation will tend to zero.

Am I correct?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: No.  Your logic is flawed.  The term $x^{1000}/1000!$ eventually overwhelms all the other terms as $x\to -\infty$.

Comment: $\infty-\infty$ is indeterminate

Comment: You are not correct, please see the answer below.

Comment: @J.W.Tanner oh yes!.. it is indeterminate.. I just missed that..

Comment: @Oliver Oloa, yes I have upvoted your answer. Thank you so much.

Comment: $\lim_{x\to{\pm\infty}}p(x)=\infty$ for all polynomials $p(x)=\sum_0^n a_k x^k$ with $n$ even and $a_n\gt 0$

Comment: Yes, I got that by now. Thank you so much. @Sam

Comment: They held me for some minutes before I could accept.. rules are rules.. haha, already done it before you asked me to.. thanks again.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One may observe that, for $x\neq0$,
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{1000} \frac{x^k}{k!}=\color{red}{\frac{x^{1000}}{1000!}}\times\left(\color{red}1+\frac{1000!}{x\times999!}+\frac{1000!}{x^2\times998!}+\cdots+ \frac{1000!}{x^{1000}\times1!}\right)
$$ giving that
$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{x \rightarrow -\infty}{\sum_{k=1}^{1000} \frac{x^k}{k!}} &=\lim_{x \rightarrow -\infty} \color{red}{\frac{x^{1000}}{1000!}}\times \lim_{x \rightarrow -\infty}\left(\color{red}1+\frac{1000!}{x\times999!}+\frac{1000!}{x^2\times998!}+\cdots+ \frac{1000!}{x^{1000}\times1!}\right)
\\\\&=\lim_{x \rightarrow -\infty} \color{red}{\frac{x^{1000}}{1000!}}\times \color{red}1
\\\\&=\infty.
\end{align}
$$